# What does $f(x)+o(j(x))=g(x)+o(h(x))$ mean exactly?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

If by $o$ we mean "little-oh", then $f(x)=o(h(x))$ means that $f\in o(h(x))$, where $$o(h(x)):=\left \{ f : \lim_{x\to a}\left| \frac{f(x)}{h(x) } \right| =0   \right \}, \text { for some } a$$

(A more precise notation might be $o_a(h(x))$, to specify which $a$ we let $x$ go to).

It seems to me that $f(x)=o(h(x))$ **is really just a non-rigorous and potentially misleading shorthand notation for the above.**

Then $f(x)=g(x)+o(h(x)),\tag 1$

I would just interpret as $(f-g)\in o(h(x))$.

This is the only rigorous way of interpreting equation $(1)$ that I can think of.

However, we might also have an equation like

$f(x)+o(j(x))=g(x)+o(h(x))\tag 2$

**In this case, I don't know how to interpret $(2)$ in a rigorous way, similar to how I interpret $(1)$?**

For example: Does it mean that **there are** $k(x)\in o(j(x)),$ and $m(x)\in o(h(x))$ such that $f(x)+k(x)=g(x)+m(x)$. Or does it mean the same but "**for all**" instead of "there are"? Or does it mean something else entirely?

---

**EDIT:** I am trying to get a general understanding of what it means when this is written down.

But to clarify what caused me to understand this question, here is a text in the calculus of variations that confused me, and led me to this question, in which a functional $J(y)=\int_a^b L(x, y(x), y'(x))dx$, for some Real valued $L$.

> [image]

When the book concludes from the third equation and equation 2.12, that equation 2.14 must hold, it seems to me that the conclusion is of the form: $$f(x)+o(x)=g(x) +o(x)\implies f(x)=g(x)$$

where in this case, $f(x)=\delta J|_y(\eta),$ and $g(x)=\int_a^b \left(L_y\cdot \eta(x) + L_z \cdot \eta '(x)\right)dx$

It is not clear to me what kind of argument that is.

Comment: It's difficult to say without any context. I'm tempted to say that things on the left side of an $=$ are a "forall" and things on the right side of an $=$ are a "there exists", so that $=$ is transitive.

Comment: @mercio, I've given my motivation, hope this helps.